# MIPS Printing a Label

Tags: printing, label, mips

I am now starting to use Mars to code In Assembly, I wrote the following code but got an error. Any ideas why?

```
.text
main:
    la $ao,Pat
    li $sv0,4
    syscall
    li $vo,10
    syscall


.data
    Pat:.asciiz "My name is Patricia"
```

Can also someone explains if there are some specific things to write before ".text" or after ".data".

Comment: The error I got is :
Error in C:\Users\Patricia\Documents\mars\print.asm line 3 column 2: "la": Too few or incorrectly formatted operands. Expected: la $t1,($t2)

Comment: None of `$ao`, `$sv0` or `$vo` are valid register names. Fix your spelling.

Answer (score 1):

```
.text
main:
    la $a0,Pat
    li $v0,4
    syscall
    li $v0,10
    syscall


.data
    Pat:.asciiz "My name is Patricia"
```

[image]

First of all `v0` is the main thing which tells the assembler what to print. Since you are printing integers, `v0` needs to be 1. The same goes for the others like:

```
float : 2
double : 3
word , string : 4
```

After giving the instruction, you can print by putting value only in a0 (its reserved for that).

So now the code will give you the result:
[Code run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6znI.png)
Earlier in your code, `sv0` was written and in some places instead of `0`. :)